# Find the modified java files between two branches after a date in git

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to find all the modified java file between two branches after the 1st of April. I could find all the modified java files with the following command. Is there anyway to apply date filter as well? Thanks

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only feature_branch..master | grep .java
```

**Solution**

Thanks @romainvaleri. I used the following command to identify the modified Java files.

```
git log --since="1st April" --name-only --pretty=format:"" feature_barnch..master -- *.java | sort -u | sed 's/.*\///'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use `git log` here for its convenient [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---sinceltdategt) :

```
git log --since="1st April" --name-only --pretty=format:"" feature_branch..master -- *.java
```

Where :

`--since=<date>` lets you set the date filter¹
`--name-only` shows only changed file names in place of changes
`--pretty=format:""` suppresses all output (namely, commit info) but the diff
`feature_branch..master` sets the range of commits to cover
and finally
`-- *.java` filters along file names

Then, if in bash context, you'll probably want to cure the list with `| sort` and `| uniq`

```
git log --since="1st April" --name-only --pretty=format:"" feature_branch..master -- *.java | sort | uniq
```

---

¹ (*which could have been relative, let's say* `--since="one month ago"`)

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. Why does --name-only flag display full path rather than just filename?

Comment: Seems you found it yourself before I could reply :-) And thanks in passing for the `-u` sort parameter, it's nicer than piping again to `uniq`

Comment: I just did what I needed to solve my problem but still I didn't get it why does --name-only flag ing git display file path?